# Linux thread state on sleep call

Tags: linux, multithreading

I have recently read some papers on the Linux thread scheduler (some simple introductions on the subject). In those the different states a linux thread can have were explained (ready, running, waiting, ...).
I'm now wondering if calling a `sleep`-like method (`sleep()` in C, `this_thread::sleep_for` in C++, `Thread.Sleep()` in C#, etc) sets the thread's state at **OS level**. Even though I guess it should, I just want to be sure, since I'm a little confused. Thanks

Comment: Try it! I think tools like `ps`, `top` or (my favourite) `htop` display the state of threads.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's what i should do. I'll try asap.

Answer (score 1):

According to what suggested [Ulrich Eckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt), I tried it by myself:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test &
$ top -H -p $(pidof test)
```

And among other stuff, I got:

```
Threads:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
```

So indeed calling a `sleep`-like function sets the OS level thread's state to 'sleeping'.